# add crittercism sdk to my ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, crittercism

I'm trying to use crittercism to know the crash in my app, the problem is that when crittercism have a crash report to send of web service, my app crash. so I can not open the app again.

The only possible to open the app is, run again the app with xcode, put a break point unit the line [Crittercism enableWithAppID:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"]; and run line per line.

In this moment crittercism send the report and I can run my app normally.

What can I do to resolve this ?

To additional information I am using, ios 8.3 in ipod 5g and xcode 6.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the founders of Crittercism here.  Which version of the Crittercism SDK are you using?  There was a small bug in v5.1.5 of the iOS SDK that we're fixing now which may be causing that issue.  If you downgrade to v5.1.3, it should work:

http://docs.crittercism.com/downloads/downloads.html

Take care
Rob

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was exactly that I wanted.